# Number of occurrences of string in an array composed by other arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've seen this question a lot, but non of them when the array contains other arrays inside.
I have an array with names of programs, here's a little example of how it looks: (my actual array has more than 3000 entries)

```
[
  ["Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["Access", "PowerPoint", "Excel", "Microsoft Project"],
  ["Access", "Outlook", "Microsoft Project", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["Access", "MS Paint", "PowerPoint", "Outlook", "Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word", "MS Planner"],
  ["PowerPoint", "Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["PowerPoint", "Excel", "Word"],
  ["Access", "MS Paint", "Skype", "PowerPoint", "Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["Access", "Outlook", "Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["PowerPoint", "Excel", "Microsoft Project"],
  ["Access", "PowerPoint", "Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["Access", "PowerPoint", "Excel", "Word"],
  ["MS Paint", "Skype", "PowerPoint", "Outlook", "Excel", "Microsoft Project", "Microsoft Teams"],
  ["Chess"]
]
```

This array comes from a survey, from a multiple choice question in which there are certain programs:

- Excel
- Microsoft Teams
- Word
- PowerPoint
- Access
- Outlook
- Other: __________

Respondents could chose as many as they want but also to add any "custom" value.

I need to count how many times each of the listed programs were selected by the respondents. But also to count all the "not listed" ones as "custom" values.
I don't know if I need to make a loop through all the items in the array, and then another loop for each of the arrays within. But I certainly don't know how to achieve that.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: No code tried shown? No expected output shown? Please consider improving your question in that way...

Comment: "I've seen this question a lot, but non of them when the array contains other arrays inside". Well, what you have is just an array of arrays, the method is not that different. Just need to add one extra loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to flatten your list, and then count each value, you can use [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for that:

```js
const values = [
  ["Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["Access", "PowerPoint", "Excel", "Microsoft Project"],
  ["Access", "Outlook", "Microsoft Project", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["Access", "MS Paint", "PowerPoint", "Outlook", "Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word", "MS Planner"],
  ["PowerPoint", "Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["PowerPoint", "Excel", "Word"],
  ["Access", "MS Paint", "Skype", "PowerPoint", "Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["Access", "Outlook", "Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["PowerPoint", "Excel", "Microsoft Project"],
  ["Access", "PowerPoint", "Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["Access", "PowerPoint", "Excel", "Word"],
  ["MS Paint", "Skype", "PowerPoint", "Outlook", "Excel", "Microsoft Project", "Microsoft Teams"],
  ["Chess"]
];

const result = values.flat().reduce((acc, x) => {
  acc[x] = (acc[x] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

If you care about performance and want to remove the flattening step, which creates second array on which reduce is applied, simply apply reduce twice, once for each level:

```js
const values = [
  ["Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["Access", "PowerPoint", "Excel", "Microsoft Project"],
  ["Access", "Outlook", "Microsoft Project", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["Access", "MS Paint", "PowerPoint", "Outlook", "Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word", "MS Planner"],
  ["PowerPoint", "Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["PowerPoint", "Excel", "Word"],
  ["Access", "MS Paint", "Skype", "PowerPoint", "Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["Access", "Outlook", "Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["PowerPoint", "Excel", "Microsoft Project"],
  ["Access", "PowerPoint", "Excel", "Microsoft Teams", "Word"],
  ["Access", "PowerPoint", "Excel", "Word"],
  ["MS Paint", "Skype", "PowerPoint", "Outlook", "Excel", "Microsoft Project", "Microsoft Teams"],
  ["Chess"]
];

const result = values.reduce((acc, x) => {
  const counts = x.reduce((out, y) => ({ ...out, [y]: (out[y] || 0) + 1 }), {});
  Object.entries(counts).forEach(([key, count]) => {
    acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + count;
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, thanks a lot! I have a question: when I want to access a certain item in the object I can do it like this: `result.Excel` to print only the Excel value, but I can't do that with values like "Microsoft Project", have an idea of how can I access this items composed for two or more words?

Comment: @Soul Eater, you can access the value with bracket access notation: `result['Microsoft Project']` instead of dot notation.

Comment: Second question: IE doesn't support `flat()`, any idea if there is a workaround, I'm using the first option you gave me. (Sorry I'm a beginner in javascript)